# Animate a menu control using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've a menu control as shown below:

```
<li id="liReportMain" class="ReportMain" runat="server">
    <a href="" title="Reports">Reports</a>
</li>
<li id="liAEReport" class="SubReport" runat="server">
    <a href="../Reports/AEReport.aspx" title="Reports">AE Report</a>
</li>
<li id="liBUEngagementReport" class="SubReport" runat="server">
    <a href="../Reports/BUEngagementReport.aspx" title="Reports">BU Report</a>
</li>
<li id="liSCReport" class="SubReport" runat="server">
    <a href="../Reports/ScoreCardDiscussionsReport.aspx" title="Reports">ScoreCard Report</a>
</li>
<li id="liRandRReport" class="SubReport" runat="server">
    <a href="../Reports/RandRReport.aspx" title="Reports">R & R Report</a>
</li>
```

Now, When the user hovers his mouse on `liReportMain`, the below report `submenus` should popup to the right. This functionality should be achieved using `jQuery`. Please help!

Comment: http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/dropdown-menu

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#liReportMain").mouseover(
    function() {
      $('#liAReport').show();
      /* the same as above with all the elements you want to show*/
    });
```

if you want to give your submenu a particular position inside your page, put the submenu elements in a div  and use css top and left properties for positioning.  In the function above you must use the show method on the div element.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS to hide the submenus by default:

```
.subReport {
  display: none;
 margin-left: 70px; // adjust this to make it float right properly

}
```

Jquery :

```
$("#liReportMain").hover(function() {
  $(".subReport").show();
}, function() {
   $(".subReport").hide();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/nedax/1/edit)